# How to dynamically addEvent to Highcharts series with multiple charts?

Tags: highcharts

I have my own Angular component that wraps a Highcharts, it works fine when I have only 1 chart if I `addEvent` on the `Highcharts.Series`, but it doesn't really work if I have multiple charts in the same component. I've tried the followings, but unable to `addEvent` to the specific chart's Series.

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { chart, setOptions, addEvent } from 'highcharts'
export class MyHighchartsComponent {

  private chart: Highcharts.Chart;

  @ViewChild('highchart', { read: ElementRef }) chartElm: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const nativeElm = this.chartElm.nativeElement;
    chart(nativeElm, options, (chartObject) => {
      this.chart = chartObject;
      // not working
      // addEvent(chartObject.series, 'click', ...);
    });


    // works, but if i have multiple charts, the click is fired on all charts
    addEvent(Highcharts.Series, 'click', ...);

    // works, but it fires everywhere, i need it from the series only
    addEvent(nativeElm, 'click', ...);

  }
}
```

What is the way to do it?

- I want to `addEvent` **dynamically**, not from the options
- I want to use the **HTMLElement**, **not** using `id`

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event on a specific series:

```
Highcharts.addEvent(chart.series[0], 'click', function() {
    console.log(this.name);
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w7Lo3af9/

---

Or add it to the all series with some condition in the event function:

```
Highcharts.addEvent(Highcharts.Series, 'click', function() {
    if (this.options.id !== 'specialSeries') {
        return false;
    }

    console.log(this.name);
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pyq5bzma/

Comment: When attaching events using the `addEvent` function, do we need to clean them all up using `removeEvent`? Or it just gets destroy when the chart object is destroyed?

Comment: I tried attaching events at `options.plotOptions.series.point` or `options.chart` and that doesn't seem to work. What is the correct way to `addEvent` there?

Comment: Hi @codenamezero, It depends if the event is added to a class or to an instance. For point class use: `Highcharts.Point`, instance: `chart.series[i].points[i]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly the info I needed. 

Can you let me know how you came across this information, which is if we need to add an event to all instances of a Class, we can call addEvent() on the class itself? Or that addEvent also can extend classes? I looked all over but only found this information in the above comment.

Comment: @ritwick__D Is available from Highcharts' API doc: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts

Comment: @ppotaczek thanks. One doubt I have is if I need to attach a click event handler to a series after the chart has been created; so that on click of each point of series, I get the (x,y) values

Are there any ways to do it other than the two above methods mentioned, ie, looping through all points of a series and attaching an event handler for all `chart.series[i].points` OR modifying the Highcharts.Point class?

Comment: I've found this information in the Highcharts source code: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/6cc12a1cd2dd797d2ea97180ac9a28487dde65dc/ts/Core/Utilities.ts#L1793 Yes, you can add an event in a loop, after chart is created, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yca3f2kL/ You can also consider adding the event directly on SVG: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#on